# What is the default port for the management service that service insight requires?

Tags: nservicebus, serviceinsight

I've installed the management service, but then I'm not sure what the default port is?

I saw the port number listed in the installer but didn't think to write it down. I had assumed that the default port would be pre-filled for me wherever I would need provide it. A google search gives lot of information on how service insight works, but sadly no one seems to need the port number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment is 33333, but we planning to change it!

Answer (score 1):

The default port is 33333. Additionally, if you are using ServiceInsight the URL required to connect will be `http://yourservername:33333/api`